# Load Balancing - Dual WAN and Static IP

Tags: networking, load-balancing, internet

I run a small business and we use a lot of AWS services (including transcoding large files) we have two internet services in the office.

A) Is a business broadband service with static IP,

B) Is another service without the potential of static IP.

I would like to balance these connections in our network to take advantage of both connections however for security many of our connections rely on the static IP for login and security, also we're looking to create a VPN in the future.

I have examined basic WAN balancing routers,  what I can't understand is that can I 'force' the static IP from service A to be always used?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You say you want to "balance" your connections (whatever that means), but then you say you want  A always to be used.  Which is it?

Comment: @RonTrunk I understand OP's wish as: OP has [Multihoming with multiple addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming#Multihoming_with_multiple_addresses) available but wishes to use it as [Classical multihoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming#Classical_multihoming) without AS, owning addresses, using a routing protocol, or a special routing contract with the two ISPs. Looks impossible to me.